# ASP.NET MVC Ajax JSON jQuery won't send parameters to `ActionResult`

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I built a half working ajax code using jQuery and JSON, but I can't get data parameters from the POST request, although I tried to send it in a few different ways (first as an object inside `data: {}` object, then as just string), but nothing worked. Here is the code:

C#, ManageController.cs:

```
public ActionResult SubmitForm(string typeAction)
        {
            string message = (int.Parse(typeAction) * 20).ToString();//Exception: can't convert null string to int
            return Json(new  {Message = message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet}); 
        }
```

JavaScript (+jQuery, of course), AppScripts.js:

```
function AjaxPost(typeofAction, ActionUrl) {    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ActionUrl,
        data: { typeAction: JSON.stringify(typeofAction) },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function () {
            return true;
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error(textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

which called from button:

```
<button onclick="AjaxPost($('#SimpleActionId').value, '/manage/SubmitForm')">Go!</button>
```

for the results, the action IS called and I can see it executed by the debugger, until exception is thrown because can't convert null string to int. the parameter doesn't even gets into the `ActionResult SubmitForm`, but it's called, and all the values are sent from the data. 
thanks.

Comment: because [model binding](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/model-binding-in-asp.net-mvc) wont take place and the string parameter will always come null

Comment: Okay. so how to get the value properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Modify your AJAX call to look like this:

```
function AjaxPost(typeofAction, ActionUrl) {    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ActionUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify({ typeAction: typeofAction }),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            return true;
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error(textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

2) Make a C# model:

```
public class ActionType
{
    public string typeAction { get; set; }
}
```

3) Change your action method to look like:

```
public ActionResult Edit(ActionType RequestModel)
{
    string message = (int.Parse(RequestModel.typeAction) * 20).ToString();
    return Json(new  {Message = message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

Now appropriate [model binding](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/model-binding-in-asp.net-mvc) will take place and you will get your `typeAction` into the  `RequestModel.typeAction` property.

Answer (score 0):

### IActionResult implementation passes some data types correctly but all strings as null.

I've isolated the error to this:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

If omitted, it is set to the [$.ajax default](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), and strings will arrive as strings to your action method.

```
contentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8,
```